# Rolling object and Friction

Tags: rotational-dynamics, friction

[image: displacement-time graph of ball 1 rolling down a ramp]

I am investigating the collision between two billiard balls. Ball 1 rolls down the ramp and collides with Ball 2 at rest on a flat surface. Because the collision between billiard balls is considered almost elastic, Ball 1 is momentarily stationary as seen in the graph. However, it's not ACTUALLY stationary: it spins (no horizontal displacement). Little bit later, Ball 1 starts rolling away on the flat surface as seen in the "secondary displacement" part of the graph.

I am looking for some explanations for this phenomena. I suspect that friction and the interaction between rotational momentum and linear momentum, but I have not been able to connect all the dots together.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ball 1 rolls down the incline and gains speed. Since the first part of your graph is linear (showing no increase in speed), I suspect the incline to have ended and the surface to be horizontal when the measurement is started, am I right?

During this horizontal rolling the ball has constant linear and rotational speed (first part of the graph). That means constant linear and rotational momentum.

When the impact happens,

- linear momentum gets transferred from one ball to the other, because one ball completely blocks the linear path of the other.
- Rotational momentum *could* also have been transferred. That would similarly require the other ball to completely block it's rotational path. But it doesn't.

Two cog wheels would be able to do that. They can interlock. But the billiard balls can't interlock. Ball 2 can't block the rotational motion of ball 1. There might be friction, but firstly I expect them to be smooth and secondly I expect the impact to be very short. Ideally no friction happens between the balls, meaning no rotational momentum transfer.

## The graph

So, looking at your graph, what happens at the stationary middle part is that ball 1 hits ball 2 and is linearly slowed down to zero. But it still rotates unchanged. Rotating while being linearly stationary means that it slides over the surface. Wheel spin. There is kinetic friction, unless the surface is very smooth right there. This kinetic friction might cause some loss in kinetic energy, meaning a loss in rotational speed.

But clearly, before all the rotational speed is gone, the ball and surface gets grip again. And when they grip, the ball starts rolling, meaning linear motion starts (it "pushes itself off" from the surface).

The rotational kinetic energy was the only energy left inside the ball at this point. Some of this energy is now being used for linear kinetic energy. Both the linear and rotational motion will therefore be slower than before, since there is less energy present to be shared between them.

Comment: There also may be a slight "jump" of the first ball when it hits the second.  It's probably not a very high jump; but that jump would cause the friction due to rotation to decrease or be temporarily eliminated completely.  If you consider some friction when the balls touch, you might expect the first ball to jump slightly as it's forward rotation rubs against the second ball.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! This definitely makes sense.
Just a question: What determines the time the ball takes to switch from rotational motion to linear motion again? Like how does it suddenly just "get grip again"?

Comment: @besnuj At impact the rotation is unchanged, ideally. There is now kinetic friction due to the sliding on the surface. This friction pulls forward. So the ball begins to move linearly again. As long as kinetic friction is present, it speeds up. Soon it moves fast enough for the periphery speed to match the ground speed. Then there is no more sliding; no more kinetic friction. Static friction takes over, and rolling starts again. All this does not take much time, I believe.

Comment: Hm, I see. Is it possible that there is any relationship between how much rotational energy is transferred and the initial velocity of ball 1?

Comment: @besnuj Well, we can calculate for how long time kinetic friction takes place, since we can find the linear acceleration that it causes (using Newton's 2nd law). We can use that time together with the initial rotational speed to calculate how much of the periphery that will slide over the surface in total. And then we can use that to calculate the work done by kinetic friction (force times total slided distance). This work is the total energy lost from the rotational kinetic friction. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Steeven All right, I think I wrapped my head around this. During the stationery interval, kinetic friction works on the slipping object, slowing down the rotational velocity and speeding up linear velocity. Once these are equal, the ball starts rolling again. Is that correct?

Comment: @besnuj Yes, correct. Although rotational and linear velocity can't become equal (different units). What actually becomes equal is the speed of the periphery and the linear speed (the centre-of-mass speed).